# problem to recognize a table through a png image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

This is I think an already asked question but I at the margin there are some new points

I have this file found on internet

[image]

and now I want to recognize the table with the following commands

```
    img = Rasterize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ricz2.png"]]
    p = StringReplace[
   TextRecognize[ImageResize[img, Scaled[4]], 
    "SegmentationMode" -> 6], {"Ell~20" -> "EU-28", "1.M" -> "1.80", 
    "2N3" -> "2003", "enigma" -> "Bulgaria"}];
```

1) I wonder why a higher scale than 4 degrades completely the recognition.
2) if there is an other way to reconstruct the table than to give a substitution table for the badly recognize texts.
3) Finally, I wonder if there is a way to ameliorate the recognition of the table

Comment: Recognizing the data from the table is an interesting question, but if you want the data you could just grab it from the [source](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/tgm/table.do?tab=table&init=1&language=en&pcode=t2020_20&plugin=1)

Comment: For sure I haven't see this page. But for some data it's the only way to import them

Comment: why are you rasterizing something that's already a raster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way to augment [@georg279's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) approach.  We can use [`ImageLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageLines.html) to subdivide the image.

First we use a derivative filter to highlight the horizontal lines.  The parameters need to be tweaked by hand.

```
img = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ricz2.png"
i2 = Binarize[DerivativeFilter[img, {1, 0}, 0.2], 0.09]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we can get the lines and inspect them:

```
lines = ImageLines[i2, 0.19, 0.008];
HighlightImage[img, {Orange, Line /@ lines}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We got every row entry, plus a block below the table, which we can discard later.  We can use the coordinates in `lines` to subdivide the image and apply `TextRecognize` to the pieces:

```
tdata = TextRecognize[ImageResize[#, Scaled[8]]] & /@ 
  Reverse@Rest[
    ImageTake[img, -Reverse@#] & /@ 
     Partition[Round@Sort@lines[[All, 1, 2]], 2, 1]]
```

We can then convert the numerals in the last ten columns to numeric data.  There's a problem with the missing data in the columns and the spaces in the names in the first column.  By padding with `"XXX"`, the entries last column were all converted, but removing the Xs took inspection.

```
Replace[
 ToExpression[(StringSplit[tdata] /. 
     "X" | "XX" | "XXX" | "xxx" :> Sequence[])[[All, -11 ;;]]],
 {x_Real :> x, n_Integer :> n, I | $Failed -> Missing["NotAvailable"]},
 2]
(*
  {{2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013},
   {1.76, 1.76, 1.78, 1.78, 1.85, 1.94, 1.93, 1.97, 2.01, 2.01}, 
   ...
   {2.49, 2.68, 2.79, 3.01, 3.21, 3.36, 3.56, 3.74, 4.04, 
    Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]},
   {2.55, 2.49, 2.51, 2.55, 2.63, 2.77, 2.82, 2.74, 2.77, 2.81, Missing["NotAvailable"]}}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

`TextRecognise` seems to fare better if you feed it smaller regions. Here I manually isolate individual lines from the table:

```
i0 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ricz2.png"];
ImageTake[i0, {60, 73}]
```

[image]

```
Column[TextRecognize[
       ImageResize[ImageTake[i0, {#, # + 13}], Scaled[8]]] & /@ 
          Range[60, 360, 16]]
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you will react to my comment : if you look at the Czech line you will see that it is shorten not only the last value is 1.79 not 1.7 but also it laks the value 1.91. It's not the only line with this behavior.

Comment: i think that's the nature of ocr, let it do most of the work and manually fix it up if you need accuracy.  The original image was obviously lossy compressed at some point so is simply not sharp enough for really good recognition.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was thinking that there was a limitation in the width that Tesseract can read.